# Pillow: Strange output creating RGB image from nxnx3 numpy matrix

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to turn an nxnx3 matrix into an RGB image, where each space in the matrix is an [R,G,B]. I thought this would be easy, but I'm getting a strange error.

I have this image: http://www.cs.brandeis.edu//~arya/test2.bmp

It's just a 10 pixel by 10 bixel bitmap with a red diagonal across it, as you can see.

And here is my python code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
imm = Image.open("test2.bmp")
t = np.int32(imm)
print(t.shape) # (10,10,3)
new = Image.fromarray(t, mode="RGB")
new.save("test_output.bmp")
```

And then I get this image: http://www.cs.brandeis.edu//~arya/test_out.bmp - very obviously different from the original output. I would expect Image.fromarray() to just create my image how it was, am I missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pillow documentation says that ["RGB" mode](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes) means 3x8-bit integers, but your array is made from 32-bit integers. Could you try `np.int8(imm)` instead?